# How to add a scala library to eclipse

Tags: scala, libraries, actor

I am trying to add [this Scala Library](https://github.com/scala/async) into Eclipse so as to add available functions I can use on Actors.

I've downloaded the file and extracted it and tried adding it to my workspace in the project explorer, but when I try, Eclipse tells me it can't find any projects in the file.  I'm sure that there is a tutorial or something online that explains exactly how to do this, but like I said, I'm not sure about all the terminology, so I don't know what to search for to get the result I want.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create an sbt project and use the [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) plugin.

Your project structure should look like this:

```
build.sbt
project/build.properties
project/eclipse.sbt
```

*build.sbt*

(note that lines of code should be separated by a white line)

```
name := "ProjectName"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" % "0.9.2"
```

*build.properties*

```
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

*eclipse.sbt*

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

Then from the root directory execute `sbt` and within the `sbt` command line execute `eclipse` or `eclipse with-sources=true`

You can use [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) or [activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) to get a specialized version that will automatically download the correct sbt version based on the `build.properties` file.

You could add the sbteclipse plugin as a default plugin, making it available in all projects by creating *eclipse.sbt* in the `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins` directory instead of the `project` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project via sbt, please follow the instruction on the github page of async. Namely, add this libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" % "0.9.2" to build.sbt, run sbt, regenerate eclipse files with "eclipse" command and finally re-import project into eclipse